# How to add categories and product form external database?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I just wanted to know about how to add or link category and product from other database. New database table fields are all most same as existing prestashop tables. Any help, hint or any helpful articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "adding or linking" an external database into Prestashop you mean making Prestashop to connect directly to the external database, I would recommend against it because will require to change the Prestashop core files making it incompatible with future upgrades of Prestashop and thus losing one of the main advantages of open source.

Instead, my recomended aproach is that the external database gets "synchronised" into the Prestashop database. It is not clear from the question whether the external database is live in another system and you just want to be able to see the same categories and products in prestashop (in catalogue mode) or on the contrary you want to stop using the application that connects to the external database and start using the data in Prestashop.

In the first scenario (live external database) the best option would be to write a script that feeds the data from the external database into the Prestashop database. If both databases are similar the script should be quite simple. Connect to both databases, query the external database and insert into the Prestashop database with any required modifications. That script could be executed with the required frequency by a cron job (e.g. once a day). Prestashop would have to be in catalogue mode so no orders can be placed (both systems cannot modifying the data or you will end up with two different sets of data).

In the second scenario, external database no longer active, the best approach would be to do a migration of the data into the Prestashop database. For the migration there are two approaches:

1) export the external database as CSV files and import it into prestashop using the import tool included by default in the Prestashop administration (Advanced Parameters -> Import CSV). This import tool allows you to assign fields from the external database into the correct fields on the Prestashop database and it takes care of all the dependencies with other tables in Prestashop. If you do not need to transform in any way your external data then I would recommend this approach.

2) Creating a script that reads the external database, does any data transformation that might be required and then inserts the transformed data into the Prestashop database. This approach is more complex but it gives you the flexibility to transform the data if required. You will have to understand all the table dependencies inside Prestashop to maintain the correct DB integrity. This is the approach that I implemented when migrating our shop into Prestashop as we had to do a significant amount of data transformation to fully take advantage of the Prestashop functionality like layered navigation, product comparison, etc.

The answer is base on my real live experience migrating our data into Prestashop. I hope it helps.

Comment: how can I understand the table dependencies inside Prestashop? Is it documented somewhere? @Jorge911

Answer (score 2):

you can add the categories from external db using a script in your prestashop site. For this create a module with frontcontroller (for cron job or to run the script) and inside the script select the categories from external db, then loop through the categories and inside the loop create prestashop category object and place the category fields to the category object and call the category save method.

```
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $temp_categs = array(); //
        //fetch data into $temp_catgs from the external db with the help mysqli_connect or whatever the driver - never modify presta db settings - write php code for db connection to external db and fetch 

        //loop through the fetched categories
        foreach($temp_categs as $categ){
          $new_categ = new Category();

          //set all the field values
          $new_categ->name = $categ['name'];
          $new_categ->id_parent = $categ['id_parent'];
          $new_categ->active = true;
          $new_categ->field2 = $categ['field2'];
          $new_categ->field3 = $categ['field3'];

          //save the category - a category with new id will be created in prestashop
          $new_categ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I Fetch the product in same way from external table ?